# Different lock behaviour when using `IN`

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, deadlock

I am having difficulty understanding the lock behaviour difference in the following examples, which cause me to have to resolve a deadlock.

I use `(updlock,holdlock)` for the common scenario of "select first, update/delete later". It might be relevant that in this specific case what is going to happen "later" is `delete`.

First, let me set up a case where everything works fine.
As a "control panel query", let's create a very simple table, add some rows, and also prepare a lock selection query based on ashman786's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365970/finding-blocking-locking-queries-in-ms-sql-mssql):

```
/*
create table color(id int primary key,descr nvarchar(50))

truncate table color
insert color(id,descr) values (0,'red'),(1,'green'),(2,'blue')
select * from color
*/
SELECT  L.request_session_id AS SPID, 
        O.Name AS LockedObjectName, 
        L.resource_type+isnull(': '+L.resource_description,'') AS LockedResource, 
        L.request_mode AS LockType 
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks L
        JOIN sys.partitions P ON P.hobt_id = L.resource_associated_entity_id
        JOIN sys.objects O ON O.object_id = P.object_id
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ES ON ES.session_id = L.request_session_id
        JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions TST ON ES.session_id = TST.session_id
        JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AT ON TST.transaction_id = AT.transaction_id
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections CN ON CN.session_id = ES.session_id
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CN.most_recent_sql_handle) AS ST
WHERE   resource_database_id = db_id()
ORDER BY L.request_session_id
```

For test 1, copy-paste each the following in a new session, each modifies one pk value:

```
select @@SPID, @@trancount
--52 is my spid
begin tran
    select * from color with (updlock,holdlock) where id=1
    delete color where id=1
commit
rollback


select @@SPID, @@trancount
--56 is my spid
begin tran
    select * from color with (updlock,holdlock) where id=2
    delete color where id=2
commit
rollback
```

Running the first line shows the SPID, which we conveniently write down in the following line.

If we create & insert the color table, then run the `begin tran` and `select` on both tabs, then the lock query shows:

```
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| SPID | LockedObjectName | LockedResource      | LockType |
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 52   | color            | PAGE: 1:704         | IU       |
| 52   | color            | KEY: (8194443284a0) | U        |
| 56   | color            | PAGE: 1:704         | IU       |
| 56   | color            | KEY: (61a06abd401c) | U        |
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Seems fine. Now run the `delete`s on both sides without committing, and we get a similar result:

```
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| SPID | LockedObjectName | LockedResource      | LockType |
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 52   | color            | PAGE: 1:704         | IX       |
| 52   | color            | KEY: (8194443284a0) | X        |
| 56   | color            | PAGE: 1:704         | IX       |
| 56   | color            | KEY: (61a06abd401c) | X        |
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Following this, committing works. A dataflow variation of one session doing both select and delete also works fine.

For test 2, instead of using the pk value as literal, we will use a temp table:

```
select @@SPID, @@trancount
--60 is my spid
begin tran
    drop table if exists #t
    select * into #t from color with (updlock,holdlock) where id=1
    delete color where id in (select id from #t)
commit

select @@SPID, @@trancount
-- 54 is my spid
begin tran
    drop table if exists #t
    select * into #t from color with (updlock,holdlock) where id=2
    delete color where id in (select id from #t)
commit
```

Running `begin tran` and `select into` on both sessions results in exactly the same lock results as before: 2xU Key locks, 2xIU Page locks. However, as soon as one of the `delete` statements is run (@60), the picture changes:

```
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| SPID | LockedObjectName | LockedResource      | LockType |
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 54   | color            | PAGE: 1:704         | IU       |
| 54   | color            | KEY: (61a06abd401c) | U        |
| 60   | color            | PAGE: 1:704         | IX       |
| 60   | color            | KEY: (8194443284a0) | X        |
| 60   | color            | KEY: (61a06abd401c) | U        |
+------+------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Changing its own U/IU to X/IX is exactly what happened previously, but this time, 60 has also a U lock on the *other* session's key! Of course, when the `delete` of the other session happens, a deadlock is formed for this reason. This seems to happen regardless of `holdlock` by the way.

So...why this difference? Will I have to make do without the temp table in order to avoid deadlocks, or is there some workaround?

Comment: In the case of the literal there is just a "Clustered Index Delete" operator. There is no separate read step to identify the row(s) to delete. In the `IN` case the read step has a clustered index scan on the outside of the nested loops and scans all rows. `delete color  from color with (forceseek) where id in (select id from #t)` avoids the issue

Comment: Adding to what @MartinSmith said, execution plans are your friend when it comes to troubleshooting deadlocks.

Comment: @Martin Smith Juicy: The FORCESEEK hint is not allowed for target tables of INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements.

Comment: you see that error if you do `delete color  with (forceseek)` but I did `delete color  from color with (forceseek) `

Comment: @Martin Smith So true! This is so much hidden knowledge. Everything worked, I consider your comments as the answer, and it was really valuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution plan for

```
delete color where id=2
```

is very simple

[image]

It just has a single "Clustered Index Delete" operator with an equality seek predicate on `id` to tell it the row to delete.

The locks taken out in this case are an `IX` lock on the table, an `IX` lock on the page containing the row, and finally an `X` lock on the key of the row to be deleted. No `U` locks are taken at all.

When using the temp table the execution plan looks as follows.

[image]

It reads each row from `color` in turn and acquires a `U` lock on it. If the semi join operator finds that there was a match for that row in the temp table the `U` lock is converted to an `X` lock and the row is deleted. Otherwise the `U` lock is released.

If the execution plan was driven by the temp table instead then it could avoid reading and locking unneeded rows in `color`.

One way of doing this would be to write the query as

```
DELETE color
FROM   color WITH (forceseek)
WHERE  id IN (SELECT #t.id
              FROM   #t)
```

[image]

The execution plan now reads the one row in #t - checks whether it exists in `color` (taking a `U` lock on just that row) and then deletes it.

As there is no constraint on `#t` ensuring that `id` is unique it removes duplicates first rather than potentially attempting to delete the same row multiple times.